# How to pass JWT token using annotations from the Microprofile Openapi swagger-ui

Tags: openapi, quarkus, microprofile

How can I pass the JWT Bearer header token to my endpoint using the annotations from the Microprofile Openapi swagger-ui?

I can pass it using curl like this:

```sh
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/users/felipe/products' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NvbS5oZWxlc3RvIiwidXBuIjoiZmVsaXBlIiwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbIlVzZXIiLCJBZG1pbiJdLCJiaXJ0aGRhdGUiOiIxOTgzLTAzLTI1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjI1MTgyMTcxLCJleHAiOjE2MjUxODI0NzEsImp0aSI6IjI2ZmYzZjczLTE0NWUtNDM2NC04NTE2LWIwNzU0YTU2YTdmYyJ9.J9S8z0IMF5XLeRfhj7u-HURSVeGUhm59Wowd56dInbC-HkKHT9aUjKN4eOeSWAWkgehBazvjkn9PZegpud1up3WRaffrx6AxYSRUAYJ205y7yjzSgbdDo6cYB3UT7dxrdcT3pczxb8X2A6YJYeOFnPoVILKlbVAJqFXAQdupLrs9V8UZCS4VGflE1AhcxQZR1rTSe6bTGeUNz4eX7vxcyL6HP_B4MhSYOnBcWtKSf1PEvPmbTfcbxK30uqA52jtSI8jMCUHw3XFTU9q_GQ4I0LMKHADj-aORGjvIZj4dZTofso_fP-ISnSnCy0qUI-Rv0yY5lHo135IgIhcz2yem5w'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy one example from the AdminApi class from the [quarkusio/registry.quarkus.io project](https://github.com/quarkusio/registry.quarkus.io/blob/main/src/main/java/io/quarkus/registry/app/admin/AdminApi.java#L58) and made some adjusts from the `SecuritySchemeType.APIKEY` to the  `SecuritySchemeType.HTTP` using [the docs of the swagger.io project about the bearer-authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/), made this annotations below and everything worked [available in this gist](https://gist.github.com/felipewind/8d199b2ac9b35abc540cac0ac0505fd9):

```java
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeIn;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.tags.Tag;

@Path("users/{user}/products")
@RequestScoped
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Tag(name = "Products")
@SecurityScheme(securitySchemeName = "Authentication",
    description = "JWT token",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    scheme = "bearer",
    bearerFormat = "JWT",
    in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER)
public class ProductResource {

    @Inject
    JsonWebToken jwt;

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed({ "User", "Admin" })
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "Authentication")
    public List<Product> getByUserName(@PathParam("user") String user, @Context SecurityContext ctx) {
        return Product.listByUserName(user);
    }

}
```

When I start my swagger-ui, I can inform the JWT token using the Authorize button:
[image]

[image]

Now, when I execute the endpoint, the swagger-ui adds the JWT token to the header:

```sh
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/users/felipe/products' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NvbS5oZWxlc3RvIiwidXBuIjoiZmVsaXBlIiwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbIlVzZXIiLCJBZG1pbiJdLCJiaXJ0aGRhdGUiOiIxOTgzLTAzLTI1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjI1MTgyMTcxLCJleHAiOjE2MjUxODI0NzEsImp0aSI6IjI2ZmYzZjczLTE0NWUtNDM2NC04NTE2LWIwNzU0YTU2YTdmYyJ9.J9S8z0IMF5XLeRfhj7u-HURSVeGUhm59Wowd56dInbC-HkKHT9aUjKN4eOeSWAWkgehBazvjkn9PZegpud1up3WRaffrx6AxYSRUAYJ205y7yjzSgbdDo6cYB3UT7dxrdcT3pczxb8X2A6YJYeOFnPoVILKlbVAJqFXAQdupLrs9V8UZCS4VGflE1AhcxQZR1rTSe6bTGeUNz4eX7vxcyL6HP_B4MhSYOnBcWtKSf1PEvPmbTfcbxK30uqA52jtSI8jMCUHw3XFTU9q_GQ4I0LMKHADj-aORGjvIZj4dZTofso_fP-ISnSnCy0qUI-Rv0yY5lHo135IgIhcz2yem5w'
```